# php multiple database field update

Tags: php

don't know if I'm missing any syntax:

```
for($i=1; $i<9; $i++)
{
    if($weekInfo == "week". $i)
    {
        //echo "d".$i;
        $Query="UPDATE databaseName SET 'd'.$i='" .addslashes($d1). "',weekInfo='" .addslashes($weekInfo). "' WHERE uid='".addslashes($uid)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($Query);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have d1 d2 d3... fields in database, if it's week1 it should save in d1 and so on.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from not using `mysql_` functions, it seems all you need are some backticks. I would also recommend you explicitly define the column name before hand. You should turn on error reporting as it will help you figure out where you issues are coming from. At the least, `echo $Query;`.

```
for($i=1; $i<9; $i++) {
    if($weekInfo == "week". $i) {
        $columnName = 'd' . $i;

        $Query="UPDATE db.table SET `$columnName` = '" .addslashes($d1). "', weekInfo='" .addslashes($weekInfo). "' WHERE uid='".addslashes($uid)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($Query);
    }
}
```